Saving KerasCV StableDiffusion model locally for reuse later on
I am using keras_cv.models.StableDiffusion to generate images from text and has the following code:
import keras_cv
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def plot_images(images):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
    for i in range(len(images)):
        ax = plt.subplot(1, len(images), i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i])
        plt.axis("off")

model = keras_cv.models.StableDiffusion(
    img_width=512, img_height=512, jit_compile=False
)

model.save("my_stable_diffusion_model.keras")

images = model.text_to_image("photograph of an astronaut riding a horse", batch_size=3)

Image.fromarray(images[0]).save("astronaut.png")
plot_images(images)

However, I get the following error message:
model.save("my_stable_diffusion_model.keras")
AttributeError: 'StableDiffusion' object has no attribute 'save'

The model that is being loaded is very large so I do not want to reload it from the Internet every single time I restart my program. Would it be possible to save the model and its weights locally so that I can reuse it?
Thanks,
Doug
